# java call applet method from javascript problem

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have a problem when call applet method from javascript..

I used this function to load applet

```
$("body").append('<applet id="asra" name="asra" code="akorbulsoundrecorder/recorder.class" archive="http://localhost/.../java/akorbulSoundRecorder.jar" width="300" height="400" MAYSCRIPT></applet>');
```

and I can call applet function javascript there is no problem;

but

```
alert(1);
document.asra.stopCapture();
alert(2);
```

`alert(1)` and `document.asra.stopCapture();` is working but `alert(2)` doesn't work?

stopCapture function

```
public void stopCapture() {

    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
        public Object run() {



            if(!test)
            jso.call("__appletRecord", new String[] {"stop"});

            targetDataLine.stop();
            targetDataLine.close();


            String filename = audioFile.getAbsolutePath();
            try {
                final ArrayList < String > cmd = getCommand(filename);
                if(!test)
                jso.call("__appletRecord", new String[] {"convertMp3"});
                Main.main(cmd.toArray(new String[cmd.size()]));
                if(!test)
                jso.call("__appletRecord", new String[] {"deleteWav"});
                //audioFile.delete();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
            }


            try {
                // Establish a connection
                if(!test)
                jso.call("__appletRecord", new String[] {"upload"});
                httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost/.../java/upload.php").openConnection();
                httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                outputStream = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
                // Buffered input stream
                fileInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\junk.mp3"));
                // Get the size of the image
                totalBytes = fileInputStream.available();
                // Loop through the files data
                for (int i = 0; i < totalBytes; i++) {
                    // Write the data to the output stream
                    outputStream.write(fileInputStream.read());
                    bytesTrasferred = i + 1;
                }
                // Close the output stream
                outputStream.close();
                if(!test)
                jso.call("__appletRecord", new String[] {"success"});
                // New reader to get server response
                serverReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()));
                // Read the servers response
                serverResponse = "";
                while ((response = serverReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    serverResponse = serverResponse + response;
                }
                if(!test)
                jso.call("__appletPHPResponse", new String[] {response});
                // Close the buffered reader
                serverReader.close();
                // Close the file input stream
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                jLabel1.setText(ex.getMessage());
            }

            return null; // nothing to return
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: How do you know that `document.asra.someMethod();` is working? Do you print something to STDOUT? If not add print at the beginning and at the end of method `someMethod()`. Then run your JS code, open the Java Console and see the result. I believe that you will find exception that will explain you everything.

Comment: I looked Java console but there is no exception.. my other method is working great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason

The reason Java is not working in IE9 is because the Java applet has been blocked by ActiveX Filtering; it is a new feature in IE9. The solution is to temporarily turn off ActiveX Filtering.

1) **How to Enable Activex filtering** -> Go to Tools in IE9 and Click on Activex Filtering, then the tick in front of the option will disappear. (It means the option is disabled.) If it is not there the option is already disabled.

If you enabled the Java loading in IE9, you may encounter a problem that the Java causes the web page to crash. We can stop this problem also, by enabling the compatibility view option in IE9. If you enabled Compatibility option then add which address you need to option that contained java applet.

2) **How to Enable Compatibility view in IE9** -> Go to Tools and click on Compatibility view settings option, then click add button and add the web site.
To remove a website from Compatibility view, just go back to Compatibility View Settings and remove the site from the Compatibility View list.

You can follow: http://chuyenhang24.com
or http://raovat2424.com